# Git rebase back and forth between two branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

First I have the following 3 branches.

```
1---2 (A)
    |\
    | 3 (B)
     \
      4 (C)
```

In order to rebase (C) on (B), I do:

```
git checkout C
git rebase B
```

and the result is:

```
1---2 (A)
     \
      3 (B)
       \
        4 (C)
```

Let's say I have committed something in (C) so I have:

```
1---2 (A)
     \
      3 (B)
       \
        4---5 (C)
```

Now I want to rebase (C) back on (A) so I would have:

```
1---2 (A)
    |\
    | 3 (B)
     \
      4---5 (C)
```

How do you do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last step you don't want to do a standard rebase, as you want to drop `3` from the history of `C`. In this case you can use interactive rebase:

```
git checkout C
git rebase -i A
```

In the resulting editor window find the line for commit `3`, remove it, save the file and close the editor. git will then rebase `4` and `5` onto `A` (`2`) while ignoring `3`.

Comment: Can't upvote because of small reputation. I will accept the answer after a bit, to see if anybody else has another idea.